How best to guide a user on the flow of a complicated web app
I am in the process of designing a really complicated system and, true to form, beta users are having a hard time navigating it and figuring out what to do. They're not using the nav menu, the tabs below the header or the user menu. They keep logging out to find pages on the marketing site (these pages are in the user menu).
I suggested a small tooltip tutorial for when the user first logs in, to guide them to a few key areas on the system. The suggestion wasn't well received.
So I'm wondering if anyone has any alternative suggestions.
The project is bound by NDA but I recreated a basic wireframe for how the flow looks at the moment.

I appreciate any insight, thanks so much!
EDIT (29/07): The platform is a combination of a VR game and an MLM platform where people can make money by means of referrals, commission, etc. So we have 2 groups of users at the moment:

Those just interested in the MLM platform (these will be the people most interested in using the dashboard) and
Gamers (primarily just interested in playing the game and not likely to play around in the dashboard area).

Our biggest problem is that the MLM users are not the most tech-savvy in the world, and so they struggle to navigate the system. In some of the cases, they did not even realise that the items at the top of the screen were clickable nav items, some didn't see the sub menu at all, so this group of people just kind of get stumped when they log in as to what their next step should be.
EDIT (31/07): For the moment, we have simply made the top global nav more visible by making the background darker, and the client has yielded for me to make a tour page for now.

Just looking at the wireframe can result in many (conflicting) ideas on how to improve the view. What could help in getting most useful answers is to update the question with use cases. What are users trying to do? What is this view used for? Probably not just to find marketing pages?

@locationunknown Thanks! I've added more context in the post

Is the 'User Menu' the global organization nav? Or, is there another global top nav bar?

@Ren The global top nav contains only the Dashboard link and the company logo to go to the main marketing site page. The user menu is the nav dropdown on the top right :)

In banking web apps, checking credit card benefits redirects you to a marketing site, with a pop-up warning. The marketing site opens in a separate browser tab. Conversely, Google wants you to be logged in for all browsing. If user data from the marketing site can be used beneficially, keeping users logged in for everything is preferable.

If your MLM users are not tech savvy one point you should consider is reduce the memory load for all the elements you have in the screen. Apply the 60-30-10 rule to the main task you are about to complete. 60% for the main container that is where these users are going to do their tasks. 30% for a left side panel where they will have access to the sub-nav-items and it could be scalable in the future, and a 10% for a top bar with the logo and the user menu. With that you get rid of the banner that I suppose it is causing a lot of noise in the users.
Also, something that is going to help you is to make agreements on what should be the problem to solve, to have in mind the user, appeal to the business and include the outcome how the business is going to benefit from your designs and lock in agreement with your PO.

